# SQLite: Return NULL fields in multiple LEFT JOIN Table

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

I have a cumbersome query I'm building in a certain way as I'll be calling it from the C-API substituting certain values.  I'm having an issue where I'm expecting NULL fields to be populating the final table.

To populate my query, I generate a date column using a recursive table expression and joining another table twice.

An example set from my table's data:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable;

id          foreignId   date        value     
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           2019-12-01  100
2           1           2019-12-02  101      
3           1           2019-12-03  102      
4           1           2019-12-04  103      
5           1           2019-12-07  104      
6           2           2019-12-01  200      
7           2           2019-12-02  201      
8           2           2019-12-03  202      
9           2           2019-12-07  203
```

The query I'm using:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates(date) AS (
  VALUES('2019-12-01')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT date(date, '+1 day')
  FROM dates
  WHERE date < '2019-12-07'
)
SELECT a.date, b.myTable, c.myTable
FROM dates a
LEFT JOIN myTable b ON a.date = b.date
LEFT JOIN myTable c ON a.date = c.date
WHERE b.foreignId = 1 AND c.foreignId = 2;
```

Returns the table:

```
date        myTable     myTable     
----------  ----------  ----------
2019-12-01  100         200      
2019-12-02  101         201      
2019-12-03  102         202      
2019-12-07  104         203
```

What I am trying to achieve:

```
date        myTable     myTable     
----------  ----------  ----------
2019-12-01  100         200      
2019-12-02  101         201      
2019-12-03  102         202
2019-12-04  103
2019-12-05
2019-12-06      
2019-12-07  104         203
```

I've tried using IFNULL in the SELECT statement like:

```
...
SELECT a.date, IFNULL(b.myTable, 0) b.myTable, IFNULL(c.myTable, 0) c.myTable
...
```

Which returns:

```
Error: near ".": syntax error
```

I'm not certain what the syntax error is, and haven't got that part working to test the result.

I've also tried using CROSS JOIN in place of LEFT JOIN and various combinations, but they return the same table as the LEFT JOIN.  Can anyone give me some guidance, particularly anything in the documentation I may have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the condition on the `left join`ed tables from the `where` clause to the `on` part of the `join`. Otherwise, rows where the `left join` comes up empty are filtered out by the `where` clause (since the conditions are not be fulfilled): this actually turns your `left join` to an `inner join`.

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates(date) AS ( ...)
SELECT a.date, b.myTable, c.myTable
FROM dates a
LEFT JOIN myTable b ON a.date = b.date AND b.foreignId = 1
LEFT JOIN myTable c ON a.date = c.date AND c.foreignId = 2;
```